# Reading json data from a authorized url with latin language?

Tags: json, r, python-3.x

I am very new in python. I have an API link, username, password to read the data. I have to read the data from the API request and then store it into a JSON file. Later I will read it in pandas or R dataframe to do more analysis. So I did:

*First approach:*

```
import requests
import json
import urllib, base64
url = 'https://abcXXXXXXXX.com/'
username = 'kebXXXXXXXXX'
password = 'XXXb8thXXXXpb8thXX'
```

The following code gives me a byte string which I am not able to export as JSON probably.

```
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).content)
```

so I decode it as:

```
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).content.decode("utf-8"))
```

which give me a list but the child text are in a European language and it does not read the proper format. In bot file the byte and decode file the text comes like that format `Dobr\u00fd den`, where `\u00fd` should be a Latin word.

*The Second Approach*:
I try to use `urllib` library.

```
URL = 'https://abcXXXXXXXX.com/'
username = b'kebXXXXXXXXX'
password = b'XXXb8thXXXXpb8thXX'
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
```

but the base64 string gives me an error: expected bytes-like object, not str. I tried different sources could not find any solution. If someone can tell me What will be the best approach to do that. My final goal is to read the JSON data, store it in a file and read by pandas or data frame and do some text analysis. Python or R solution will be ok.

The data looks like(sample):

```
[
"messages": [
            {
            "type": "agent",
            "name": "",
            "from": null,
            "content": "Hezký den, potřebujete poradit s výběrem eliptického trenažeru?",
            "sentAt": 1509526170320,
            "triggeredBy": "Eliptický trenažér",
            "email": null
            }
            ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not aware, `requests` result objects have a [`.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content). This should automatically decode the content for you, assuming the results have returned in a json format. Some APIs require an extra header. The line that you wrote,

```
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).content)
```

would change to something like

```
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).json())
```

if headers are not necessary or

```
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}).json())
```

if they are.